# Lightbox 2 Hover Effect

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox2

Please how can I add a cool hover effect on my light box 2 image gallery? Am using bootstrap and the gallery is working fine but I need an hover effect.

This is my HTML code.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
  <a href="images/portf/thumb/1.jpg" data-title="first image" data-lightbox="port">
    <img src="images/portf/thumb/1.jpg" class="img-responsive no-padding  wow fadeInLeft" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/OriginalHoverEffects/index3.html

There is a few nice effect, do you need help with implementation, or you wanna use something specific from bootstrap?

You can choose one of these I can help you with implementation then 
http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/